# How can I get div content into a drop down in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

First post so if im doing something wrong please say so.

Let me explain this properly. Im building a site using HTML5, CSS3 and Bootstrap3. I have an area near the bottom of the page which contains various headers which act as categories, with links listed below. In desktop view it looks fine, but it looks very cluttered and untidy in mobile view.

A solution to this problem would be to make the headings into drop-downs - but for mobile view only. I have no clue how to do this and how to do this for mobile only, maybe I could use the hidden properties to display the content in different ways.I did some quick drawings to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

Desktop view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef4Xn.png

Mobile view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgAr8.png

So In mobile view the headers will display as columns and once clicked will expand show the links, and can then be clicked again to close. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this or show me similar solutions with example code, I would be very grateful as I am new to Bootstrap and creating responsive sites.

Current Desktop Code:

```
        <div class="header2">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="sitem grey gsm20"> Site Information </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> About us </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> FAQS</p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Blog </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Contact Us </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">

        <p class="sitem grey gsm20"> Service and Support </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> My Account </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Payment Methods </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Privacy & Cookies </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Terms & Conditions </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Insurance </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="sitem grey gsm20"> Delivery & Returns </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Delivery Tracking </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Delivery Prices </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Returns </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Responsibility </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Shipping and Handling </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="sitem grey gsm20"> Contact </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Address Line 1 </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Address Line 2 </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Town </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> County </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> POST CODE </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> 0208 961 4545 </p>
        <p class="red gsm16"> info@example.co.uk </p>
        <p class="white"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="grey gsm20"> Latest Blog Feed </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur adipiscing </p>
        <p class="grey gsm16"> Posted in industrial coatings on 10th January 2015 </p>
        <p class="white gsm16"> Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur adipiscing
        Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur adipiscing
        Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur adipiscing
        Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur adipiscing</p>
        <p class="red gsm16"> Read More >> </p>

        </div>
    </div><!--Row-->
</div><!--Container-->
</div><!--Header2-->
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction for how to implement a solution such as this? I would be grateful as I am unsure of where to start, my searches seem to bring up irrelevant articles so if someone has found something useful before could you send me a link please.

Kind Regards, Shaun Naylor

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your example code? Take time to read "[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.. I didn't think code would be necessary as I was simply looking for a link of some sort which would explain how to implement such a solution, I will try to edit my question.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not a coding service, we expect people who ask a question to have at least tried it themselves first.

Comment: Never assumed or said that you are a coding service. I can see how the post is worded that can make one assume that it is my intention, I will update it accordingly, I don't expect someone to provide a fully fledged solution, I am unsure how to do this, so I am asking if someone can show me example code or explain the principles of this solution so that I can learn and understand for my current project and future projects.

Kind Regards, Shaun

Comment: He is just asking for hint not for code.. What you are trying to attend can be done by many way -> have a look to bootstrap anchor, media queries and eventually js/jQuery for animation part.

Comment: I checked Bootstrap docs but all I can seem to find is drop-downs for links, perhaps I can adapt this. I will look into Bootstrap Anchor, Thank you Baldráni.

Kind Regards, Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Since you've added the tag Bootstrap I assume you know of the framework. Why wont you just use the ordinary Bootstrap solution? You could either create 2 different menus (which i do not recommend) and hide one of them like this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Or another solution is to use a Bootstrap menu like in this example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ and customize it yourself.

There is always the solution of creating a Script yourself, but i dont think that is neccessary when you can just use the framework tools.

Comment: Yeah im having a mess around with the drop-down menu, I can get a drop-down working but it comes down like an option select. Im trying to a achieve a full div to drop-down when the heading is clicked as opposed to a small menu with some options. Kind Regards, Shaun

Answer (score 0):

refer the below code. it will show bind the data into a drop down. on load. you can show the drop down only on mobile window using media query

```js
  $(function () {
            // Create the  dropdown
            $("<select />").appendTo(".footleft");
            // Create default option "Go to..."
            $("<option />", {
                "selected": "selected",
                "value": "",
                "text": "Go to..."
            }).appendTo(".footleft select");
            // Populate dropdown with menu items
            $(".footleft a").each(function () {
                var el = $(this);
                $("<option />", {
                    "value": el.attr("href"),
                    "text": el.text()
                }).appendTo(".footleft select");
            });
            $(".footleft select").change(function () { window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); });

        });
```

```css
.footnav { margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; display: block; }
        .footnav > li { margin: 6px 0; padding: 0; }
        .footnav > li > a { display: block; padding: 0 6px; line-height: 14px; color:#a1a1a1; font-size: 13px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footleft">
        <ul class="footnav">
            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms & Condition</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Investor Grievances</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RMS Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dormant Account Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```